# When using KNeighborsClassifier what is the motivation of using weights="distance"

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn

When using `KNeighborsClassifier` what is the motivation of using `weights="distance"` ?

According to sklearn [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html):

> ‘distance’ : weight points by the inverse of their distance. In this case, closer neighbors of a query point will have a greater influence than neighbors which are further away.

What is the motivation of using this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of a nearest-neighbors classifier is to consider those points of the training set which are close to the point you want to classify, and guess this point's class based on their known class labels.

If all these close training points have the same label, the result is clear. But what if they don't all have the same label? You could take their most common label, but this may not always be the best guess.

For example, imagine one training point with label A being very close to the point you want to classify, while two training points with label B are somewhat further away, but still close. Should the new point be labelled A or B? Weighting the points by how close they are (i.e. by the inverse of their distance) provides an objective way to answer this question.